# Apache mod_rewrite not redirecting to PHP, but redirecting to other URLs

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have a code in my .htaccess file.. It redirect every .php to non php. I want it to only direct one php file and dont redirect the rest.. forexample i want abc.php to be abc but bcd.php stays as bcd.php.. How can i modify this script to get this result? thanks.

```
RewriteEngine on
#Redirect non-php to php and stop futher processing
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

#redirect .php to non-php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: "It redirect every .php to non php" - That's a lie. It redirects non-php to php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should work for you:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(abc)\.php[?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

#Redirect non-php to php and stop futher processing
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Important to use `%{THE_REQUEST}` here which represents original HTTP request as received by Apache to avoid looping. `%{THE_REQUEST}` doesn't get rewritten with various rewrite rules as opposed to the case with URI pattern used for `RewriteRule`.

Comment: Thank u very much.. Your code is working too.. But i am confused.. How can i understand if its looping or not? Is there a way to check it?

Comment: Unfortunately all online .htaccess rewrite are unreliable. I had tested other code myself and it caused looping.

Answer (score 0):

Put the rule with exception and L flag before the general RewriteRule:

```
RewriteEngine on
#redirect abc.php to abc
RewriteRule ^abc\.php$ abc [R=301,L]

#Redirect non-php to php and stop futher processing
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ! abc$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: This is guaranteed to cause looping.

Comment: thank you.. it looks like working.. how do you understand if it cause looping or not?

Comment: @EnginErdoğan It won't cause looping, cause abc is not a php file. So the second RewriteCond will protect you from the loop

Comment: @anubhava Can you prove, that it will cause a loop? The PO says it doesn't. I also said about why in my opinion it won't cause a loop.

Comment: Thank you.. is there a way to understand if it cause looping or not?

Comment: @EnginErdoğan If it was an eternal loop, you would have gotten an error message from Apache. As you didn't get it, it works correctly. This condition: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f` protects you.

Comment: I wouldn't have commented without testing it myself that it is causing looping.

Comment: @anubhava ok, I'll take a look

Comment: If you try & understand mod_rewrite it will be clear why it is looping. 2nd `RewriteRule` will inject `abc.php` and first rule will make it `abc` again which will be injected and then matched by 2nd rule. This will go forever until Apache throws 500.

Comment: @anubhava Thanks for the proof. Got your idea. I added an extra condition `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ! abc$`, that will block the second Redirect from firing.